# Format Tablix with Row Grouping in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to format a dataset in SSRS for readability and to meet design specifications.  My dataset is returning expected values and I have created appropriate Row Groups, or at least I believe I have, for the report and when I preview the report - it looks correct, but just not the way I need it formatted.

The first two images are how I have the tablix formatted in SSRS and the row grouping I created.

[image: Tablix]

[image: Row Grouping]

And how the report looks when run:

[image: Report Preview]

And lastly, I have drawn a mockup of how I am hoping to format the tablix for this particular report - which includes having each particular row group in it's own row and the details ( questions and answers ) appear on on a separate row as well. The first section is the template while the rest is an example of data in the format I wish to have:

[image: Template]

Anyone have any advice on how this could be accomplish?

Comment: Check out this link: https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/ssrs-create-child-group-in-same-column-below-parent/

Comment: I'll take a look at this link and see if it can help me.

Comment: That link helped me achieve my desired result - but it's in a comment so I cannot mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your report like this:
[image]

Comment: I tried removing the Details row and it did not result in the desired format.